# JQuery dialog is it possible to dynamically load the content?

Tags: jquery

What I would like to do is to load dynamic content into a dialog box instead of having to define a function for every box I need. It just seems like having a single function to do this would be a better way to go. Is there any documentation how this can be accomplished? I've looked on JQuery's site but can't find anything helpful.

Comment: Where are you getting this "dynamic content"? In the same page (maybe just hidden) or from server-side?

Comment: You have to define a function for each event you want to capture but you could call a common function from that function ... what have you tried?

Comment: I want to send it over from the server.

Comment: Cfreak, I haven't tried very much as I'm really new to JQuery. I had this functionality from a project that I worked on a year ago and can't find it now. If there is an article on this, can someone please point me to it? I'm not even sure what it's called that I need.

Comment: Please do research about ajax load your content dynamically through it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ajax you can do this. On the success function of ajax call you have to DO two things:

1. Call the ui dialog open function.
2. Write the content to a specific div using innerHTML OR html() in jQuery.

Comment: OK, this makes sense. I'll credit you for the answer when the timer expires. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

See the example i am sure this will help you [prototype](http://prototype-window.xilinus.com/samples.html#ajax_dialog_click_button)

Comment: For example : You have 10 buttons and you want to open box on their click according to them. then you call a function on their click which will accept some parameter and use ajax to get the content according to it after that you will load the content received through ajax in dialogue box body and at the end you will show the dialogue `????.dialog( "open" );`